# Apache POI pivot table with horizontal columns

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I hava data for excel like this 
[image]
When I want to generate pivot table with code below

```
XSSFSheet pivot = wb.createSheet("pivot");
AreaReference areaReference = new AreaReference("A2:D" + i, SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);
CellReference cellReference = new CellReference("A1");

XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = pivot.createPivotTable(areaReference, cellReference, sheet);

pivotTable.addRowLabel(1);
pivotTable.addRowLabel(2);

pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 3);
```

I got next result 
[image]
But want something like this
[image]

What I do wrong?

Comment: Does the answer solving your question? If so, why you don't accept the answer? If not, why you don't comment this somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's name tells `addRowLabel` adds a row label. But you wants column `C` (2) of your `data` sheet to be a column label. Up to `apache poi` version 3.17, the only way to achieve this is using the underlaying  low level objects. But this needs knowledge about the internals of pivot tables.

Best way to investigate the internals is creating a `*.xlsx` file having a pivot table using `Excel`'s GUI. This `*.xlsx` file is nothing else than a `ZIP` archive. So we can unzip it and taking a look into. There we will find `XML` files for the worksheets in `/xl/worksheets`, the pivot table definitions in `/xl/pivotTables` and the pivot caches in `/xl/pivotCache`. According to this `XML` we then can programming using the low level objects of package `org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.*`.

Example:

[image]

Code:

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.SpreadsheetVersion;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

class PivotTableCreating {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

  XSSFWorkbook wb = (XSSFWorkbook)WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("PivotExample.xlsx"));

  XSSFSheet pivotSheet = wb.createSheet("pivot");

  XSSFSheet dataSheet = wb.getSheet("data");
  int lastRowNum = dataSheet.getLastRowNum();

  XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = pivotSheet.createPivotTable(
   new AreaReference(new CellReference("data!A1"), new CellReference("data!D" + (lastRowNum+1)), 
   SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007),
   new CellReference("A5"));

  pivotTable.addRowLabel(1);

  pivotTable.addRowLabel(2); //column C as a row label = RowField and AXIS_ROW

  //do changing column C as a col label
  pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(2)
   .setAxis(org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STAxis.AXIS_COL); //AXIS_COL

  //remove column C from RowFields
  pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getRowFields().removeField(1); 
  pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getRowFields().setCount(1);

  //create ColFields for column C
  pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().addNewColFields().addNewField().setX(2); 
  pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getColFields().setCount(1);

  pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 3);

  wb.write(new FileOutputStream("PivotExampleNew.xlsx"));
  wb.close();

 }
}
```

Result:

[image]

As shown in the `API` -  [XSSFPivotTable](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFPivotTable.html) there is further development (`addColLabel`). But the current (May 2018) latest stable version `apache poi` version 3.17 does not providing this.

Comment: It's working. Thanks a lot. Is there any doc about? While it's working want to know how it does. Not everything is clear for me.

Comment: @Alex: As told, this needs knowledge about the internals of pivot tables. I have edited my answer adding informations for how to investigate the internals.

Answer (score 0):

Try to perfrom following code on your date column:

```
pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(5).setAxis(STAxis.AXIS_COL)
pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(5).addNewItems();
pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(5).getItems().addNewItem()
            .setT(STItemType.DEFAULT);
```

Replace the `5` with the number you need (I assume `2`). This code turns the axis of the column

Comment: sorry for late answer, missed notification from site. Didn't help. Played with that lines in all variants: before labels, after labels, before data, after. No luck. Separate question about POI part with schema is there any docs, or where you got that lines?

Comment: Sadly I can't find the question right now, but it is somewhere on SO. On tuesday I can check the full code and hopefully provide more info.